# Im have some problems to start my android application with google apis maps

Tags: java, android

when i try to start my android application on android studio emulator
Android emulator version: API 21 GOOGLE APIS.

i got this message.

```
 10-07 13:21:46.668    2296-2296/com.example.talisson.googlemapteste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.talisson.googlemapteste, PID: 2296
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.talisson.googlemapteste/com.example.talisson.googlemapteste.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.talisson.googlemapteste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.talisson.googlemapteste:color/abc_color_highlight_material" (7f0c0053)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0c0053 a=-1 r=0x7f0c0053}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:64)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:912)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:966)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.talisson.googlemapteste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

here is my mainactivity code

```
package com.example.talisson.googlemapteste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LatLng location = new LatLng(-19.0506,-43.0555);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    EditText llatitude;
    EditText llongitude;

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeMap();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void buttonOnClick(View v){
        llatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLat);

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(llatitude.getText().toString());

        llongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLong);
        double longi = Double.parseDouble(llongitude.getText().toString());
        location  = new LatLng(lat,longi);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Olá,mundo"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 20));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10),200,null);

    }

    private void initializeMap()
    {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.Map)).getMap();
        }
        if(googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Olá,mundo"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 40));

        }

    }



}
```

i Would like to know what is the problem. 
it Worked before i close Android Studio and now isn´t working anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the .XML you used in MainActivity.

If i look at the at the error message it see three lines that really matter.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.talisson.googlemapteste/com.example.talisson.googlemapteste.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error
>   inflating class Button
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)

and this line

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.example.talisson.googlemapteste:color/abc_color_highlight_material"
>   (7f0c0053)  is not a Drawable (color or path):
>   TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0c0053 a=-1 r=0x7f0c0053}

and this one too

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53:
>   Error inflating class Button

It suggests that you are trying to use the color/abc_color_highlight_material in your button, but that it's not a drawable. Check your XML at line 53 and modify this line. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks alot sir , you just answer my question. And now i know where to see my mistakes. Keep helping people plis.